# Why is list of lists not behaving as expected?

Tags: python, spyder

I have a list of lists. it contains about 30k lists. I am trying to access the 3rd element of each sub-list.

```
[subl[3] for subl in d]
```

I keep getting `IndexError: list index out of range` error.

The problem is that if I manually create the list, my code works fine:

```
lst = [['https:', '', 'www.some site.zxy', 'val 4', 'val5 ', 'val 6'],
['https:', '', 'www.some site.zxy', 'val 4', 'val5 ', 'val 6']]

print([subl[3] for subl in lst])
```

I have noticed if I print out the lists (using spyder), the little one I created above is in black text, but my large list of lists is in red text. I don't know what this indicates.

Comment: Post some portion of the list on which your code fails.

Comment: Some sublists dont have a 4th element!

Comment: `assert all(len(i) > 3 for i in lst), "not all sublists are long enough"`

Comment: Bingo! This is it! Thank you! I should have seen this, but relatively new to python.

Comment: Please post a __verifiable__ example. If we cannot reproduce the problem, we cannot know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if your list has the required number of elements

**Ex:**

```
lst = [['https:', '', 'www.some site.zxy', 'val 4', 'val5 ', 'val 6'],
['https:', '', 'www.some site.zxy', 'val 4', 'val5 ', 'val 6']]

print([subl[3] for subl in lst if len(subl) > 3])
```

Comment: he is asking for 3rd element not 4th

Comment: @xyz. Its just an example. You can modify it any way you want